# statistique descriptive table with multiple panels

Tags: tables

i will be grateful if you can help in creating a table like this? , here is my code and a caption of what i wanted

```
     \begin{table}
     \caption{Descriptive statistics}
     \label{tab1}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{d{2.4}d{2.2}d{2.4}} @{}}
        \toprule
      Variables & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Domestic FIRMS} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Foreign FRIMS} \\ 
      \cmidrule(l){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
         \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule{4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule{7-7}
         & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Min} & \mc{SD}&\mc{Mean} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Min} & \mc{SD}\\ 
      \midrule
      XLLs          & 1.05  & 21  & 7.01 & 0.73 & 0.13 & 0.07& 0.07 & 0.07\\
      Log Z_{PMD}  & 10.7  & 12.1 & 6.98 & 0.77 & 0.16 & 0.1& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      ESSAI Connections      & 4.75  & 0    & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Cep_{PF}      & 4.75  & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.07& 0.07\\
      Ad_{ENd}       & 4.75  & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.07& 0.07\\
      Size (LNYA)  & 4.831 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Capitalization (DEY) & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      liquidity (LRT)       & 4.83& 1.07 & 4.67& 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Profitability (PYF)   & 4.83& 1.07 & 4.67& 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Equality (ECD)      & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.6 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Leverage(LEV)        & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Loan growth (Ld)      & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Price growth (PG)     & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Diversification(DTV)  & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     MAS                   & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     PCS                   & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
     \end{table}
```

here what I wanted as an outcome :
[image]

Comment: Please make your code compialble. How is the `d` column type and the `\mc` command defined? Which documentclass do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
     \begin{table}
     \caption{Descriptive statistics}
     \label{tab1}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{ l d{-2.3} d{2.2} *{6}{d{1.2}} @{}}
        \toprule
      Variables & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Domestic FIRMS} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Foreign FRIMS} \\ 
      \cmidrule(l){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
         & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Min} & \mc{SD}&\mc{Mean} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Min} & \mc{SD}\\ 
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Panel A: Risk measures}\\ 
      \addlinespace
      XLLs          & 1.05  & 21  & 7.01 & 0.73 & 0.13 & 0.07& 0.07 & 0.07\\
      Log Z\_{PMD}  & 10.7  & 12.1 & 6.98 & 0.77 & 0.16 & 0.1& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Panel B:......}\\
      \addlinespace 
      ESSAI Connections      & 4.75  & 0    & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Cep{PF}      & 4.75  & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.07& 0.07\\
      Ad\_{ENd}       & 4.75  & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.07& 0.07\\
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Panel C:......}\\ 
      \addlinespace
      Size (LNYA)  & 4.831 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Capitalization (DEY) & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      liquidity (LRT)       & 4.83& 1.07 & 4.67& 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Profitability (PYF)   & 4.83& 1.07 & 4.67& 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      Equality (ECD)      & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.6 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Leverage(LEV)        & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Loan growth (Ld)      & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Price growth (PG)     & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     Diversification(DTV)  & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Panel D:......}\\
      \addlinespace
     MAS                   & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     PCS                   & 4.83 & 1.07 & 4.67 & 0.79 & 0.2 & 0.73& 0.07& 0.07 \\
     \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
     \end{table}
     \end{document}
```