# A long one-column tabularx table (with multirow) in a two column document

Tags: longtable, tabularx, two-column, multirow

I have a very long column that spans more than one page. I used the tabularx environment to create the table but, as you may know, it doesn't work alone for such large tables. In addition, my document is two-column and I want the table to be one column while maintaining the rest of the document in the two-column mode. The table also uses multirow.
How can I achieve such a table? All comments will valuable. Thanks!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % Cambio de idioma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación de entrada
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Codificación de fuente
\usepackage{lmodern} % Fuente compatible
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \title{Example}
    \author{Sergio}
    \maketitle{}
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[2-4] 
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Section I}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{Section II}  
        \lipsum[1-5]
        \begin{table*}[htb]
            \centering
            \caption{Compuestos químicos aislados a partir de la flor}\label{tab:Table1}    
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXc}\hline
                Compuesto químico     &  Tipo & Referencia\\ \hline
                Matricina            & \multirow{2}{*}{\centering Sesquiterpeno} &   [1]    \\
                Matricarina          &  &   [1] \\
                \hline
                Matricolona           & \multirow{6}{*}{\centering Sesquiterpeno lactona} & [1]\\
                Dihidroridentina      &                                                   &  [1]\\
                2-$\alpha$-hidroxiarborescina &                                           &  [1]\\
                Achilina              &                                                   & [1]\\
                Leucodina             &                                                   & [1]\\
                Acetoxiachilina       &                                                   & [1]\\
                \hline
                Apigenina             & \multirow{20}{*}{\centering Flavonoide}            & [1]\\
                Luteolina             &                                                   & [1]\\
                Quercetina            &                                                   & [1]\\
                Patuletina            &                                                   & [1]\\
                Isoramnetina          &                                                   & [1]\\
                Jaceidina             &                                                   & [1]\\     
                Crisosplenol D        &                                                   & [1]\\
                Crisosplentin         &                                                   &  [1]\\
                Eupatoletina          &                                                   & [1]\\
                Espinacetina          &                                                   & [1]\\
                Axilarina             &                                                   & [1]\\
                Eupalitina            &                                                   & [1]\\
                Galangina             &                                                   & [1]\\
                Kaempferol            &                                                   & [1]\\
                Hispidulina           &                                                   & [1]\\
                6-metoxi-kaempferol   &                                                   & [1]\\
                Eupafolina            &                                                   & [1]\\
                3-metil-quercetina    &                                                   & [1]\\
                Ermanina              &                                                   & [1]\\
                5,7,4'-trihidroxi-3,6-dimetoxiflavonona &                                 & [1]\\
                \hline  
                Apigenina-7-glucósido & \multirow{23}{*}{\centering Glicósido flavonoide} &  [1]\\
                Apigenina-7-apiosil-glucósido &                                           &  [1]\\
                Isoquercitrina &                                                          &  [1]\\
                Luteolina-7-glucósido &                                                   & [1]\\
                Luteolina-4'-glucósido &                                                  & [1]\\
                Luteolina-7-rutinósido &                                                  &  [1]\\
                6-hidroxi-luteolina-7-glucósido &                                         &  [1]\\
                Quercetina-7-glucósido &                                                  &  [1]\\
                Rutina                 &                                                  &  [1]\\
                Hiperina               &                                                  & [1]\\
                Patuletina-7-glucósido &                                                  &  [1]\\
                Isoramnetina-7-glucósido &                                                &  [1]\\
                Crisoeriol-7-glucósido &                                                  &  [1]\\
                6''-malonil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                               &  [1]\\
                4''-acetil-6"-malonil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                     &  [1]\\
                6''-cafeoil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                               &  [1]\\
                4''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                              &  [1]\\
                3''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                              &  [1]\\
                2''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                                      &  [1]\\
                6''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                                      &  [1]\\
                2'',3''-diacetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                                & [1]\\
                3'',4''-diacetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido &                                &[1] \\
                Palmatósido A                            &                                & [1]\\
                \hline
                Ácido oleanólico                         &           Triterpeno           & [1]\\
                \hline
                $\beta$-sitosterol glucósido & \multirow{2}{*}{\centering Glicósido fitoesterol} & [1]\\
                Estigmasterol-3-glucósido &                                                      & [1]\\  
                \hline
                $\beta$-sitosterol & \multirow{2}{*}{\centering Fitoesterol} & [1]\\
                Estigmasterol &                                              & [1]\\
                \hline
                Matriisobenzofurano & Benzofurano & [1]\\
                \hline
                Ácido-(E)-glucometoxicinámico & \multirow{2}{*}{\centering Ácido cinámico} & [1]\\
                Ácido-(Z)-glucometoxicinámico &                                   & [1]\\
                \hline
                \emph{p}-hidroxiacetofenona & \multirow{18}{*}{\centering Fenólico} & [1]\\
                Ácido 5-cafeoilquínico &                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 3-cafeoilquínico &                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 4-cafeoilquínico &                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 1-\emph{O}-glicósido-ferúlico &                              & [1]\\
                Ácido 7-\emph{O}-glicósido-ferúlico &                              & [1]\\
                Ácido-1,3-dicafeoilquínico &                                       & [1]\\
                Cafeato de etilo           &                                       & [1]\\
                Ácido neoclorogénico &                                             & [1]\\
                Ácido clorogénico &                                                & [1]\\
                Ácido criptoclorogénico &                                          & [1]\\
                Ácido 3,4-dicafeoilquínico &                                       & [1]\\
                Ácido 3,5-dicafeoilquínico &                                       & [1]\\
                Ácido 4,5-dicafeoilquínico &                                       & [1]\\
                Ácido isoclorogénico B &                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido isoclorogénico C &                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 4-hidroxi-benzoico &                                         & [1]\\
                5-pentadecylbenceno-2,3-diol &                                     & [1]\\
                \hline
                Herniarina & \multirow{10}{*}{\centering Cumarina}                 & [1]\\
                Dafnina                      &                                     & [1]\\
                Dafnetina                    &                                     & [1]\\
                Esquimina                    &                                     & [1]\\
                Umbeliferona                 &                                     & [1]\\
                Esculetina                   &                                     & [1]\\
                Cumarina                     &                                     & [1]\\
                Isoescopoletina              &                                     & [1]\\
                Escopoletina                 &                                     &[1] \\
                Fraxidina                    &                                     &[1] \\
                \hline
                7,22-dieno-3,5,6-trihidroxiergosterol & \multirow{13}{*}{\centering Esteroide}  &[1] \\
                3-$\beta$-hidroxi-5-$\alpha$,8-$\alpha$-epidioxyergosta-6,22-dieno &            &[1] \\
                3-$\beta$-hidroxi-(22\emph{E},24\emph{R})-ergosta-5,8,22-trien-7-ona &          & [1]\\
                6-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmasta-4,22-dien-3-ona &                                   & [1]\\
                6-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmastero-4-en-3-ona &                                      &[1] \\
                Estigmast-22-eno-3,6-diona               &                                      & [1]\\
                5-$\alpha$-estigmasta-3,6-diona          &                                      & [1]\\
                7-$\alpha$-hidroxiestigmasterol          &                                      &[1] \\
                7-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmasterol           &                                      &[1] \\
                7-$\alpha$-hidroxisitosterol             &                                      & [1]\\
                7-$\beta$-hidroxisitosterol              &                                      &[1] \\
                $\beta$-sitosterol                       &                                      &[1] \\
                Fitol                                    &                                      & [1]\\
                \hline
                Ácido quínico                            & Ciclitol                           &[1] \\
                \hline
                Camolol                                  & Glicósido                            & [1]\\
                \hline
                Bracteósido                              & Flavonoide glucurónido                & [1]\\
                \hline
                Coniferil isovalerato dimérico           & Neolignano                            & [1]\\
                \hline
                Glicerol monopalmitato                   & Monoglicérido                         & [1]\\
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table*}
    \section{Section III}
    \lipsum[1-5]    
    \section{Section IV}
        \lipsum[1-20]
    
\end{document}
'''
```

Comment: Take a look at the `supertabular` package. It does not define a flexible width `X` type column, but you should be able to get away using fixed width `p` type columns.

Comment: Combining `\multirow` with page breaking tables, especially if the `\multirow` spans a larger number of rows, is often somewhat risky as it could lead to overlaps with the footer. Probably you could redesign your table to just use 2 instead of 3 columns and divide your table into multiple panels, instead. (For an example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553163/134144)

Comment: I would set that using a list not a table

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try the supertabular package suggestion. I've been trying the xltabular package too, but it seems to be not compatible with multirows.

Comment: See, if answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161431 can help you.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following redesign?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % Cambio de idioma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación de entrada
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Codificación de fuente
\usepackage{lmodern} % Fuente compatible
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\newlength{\rightcolwidth}
\setlength{\rightcolwidth}{\widthof{Referencia}}
\newlength{\leftcolwidth}
\setlength{\leftcolwidth}{\linewidth-3\tabcolsep-\rightcolwidth}

\begin{document}
    \title{Example}
    \author{Sergio}
    \maketitle{}
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[2-4] 
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Section I}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{Section II}  
        \lipsum[1-5]

            \tablecaption{Compuestos químicos aislados a partir de la flor\label{tab:Table1}}    
            \tablehead{\toprule Compuesto químico & Referencia \\ \midrule} 
            \begin{supertabular}{p{\leftcolwidth} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\rightcolwidth}r@{}}
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Sesquiterpeno}\\
                Matricina                                                            & [1]\\
                Matricarina                                                          & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Sesquiterpeno lactona}\\
                Matricolona                                                          & [1]\\
                Dihidroridentina                                                     & [1]\\
                2-$\alpha$-hidroxiarborescina                                        & [1]\\
                Achilina                                                             & [1]\\
                Leucodina                                                            & [1]\\
                Acetoxiachilina                                                      & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Flavonoide}\\
                Apigenina                                                            & [1]\\
                Luteolina                                                            & [1]\\
                Quercetina                                                           & [1]\\
                Patuletina                                                           & [1]\\
                Isoramnetina                                                         & [1]\\
                Jaceidina                                                            & [1]\\     
                Crisosplenol D                                                       & [1]\\
                Crisosplentin                                                        & [1]\\
                Eupatoletina                                                         & [1]\\
                Espinacetina                                                         & [1]\\
                Axilarina                                                            & [1]\\
                Eupalitina                                                           & [1]\\
                Galangina                                                            & [1]\\
                Kaempferol                                                           & [1]\\
                Hispidulina                                                          & [1]\\
                6-metoxi-kaempferol                                                  & [1]\\
                Eupafolina                                                           & [1]\\
                3-metil-quercetina                                                   & [1]\\
                Ermanina                                                             & [1]\\
                5,7,4'-trihidroxi-3,6-dimetoxiflavonona                              & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Glicósido flavonoide}\\
                Apigenina-7-glucósido                                                & [1]\\
                Apigenina-7-apiosil-glucósido                                        & [1]\\
                Isoquercitrina                                                       & [1]\\
                Luteolina-7-glucósido                                                & [1]\\
                Luteolina-4'-glucósido                                               & [1]\\
                Luteolina-7-rutinósido                                               & [1]\\
                6-hidroxi-luteolina-7-glucósido                                      & [1]\\
                Quercetina-7-glucósido                                               & [1]\\
                Rutina                                                               & [1]\\
                Hiperina                                                             & [1]\\
                Patuletina-7-glucósido                                               & [1]\\
                Isoramnetina-7-glucósido                                             & [1]\\
                Crisoeriol-7-glucósido                                               & [1]\\
                6''-malonil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                           & [1]\\
                4''-acetil-6"-malonil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                 & [1]\\
                6''-cafeoil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                           & [1]\\
                4''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                            & [1]\\
                3''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                            & [1]\\
                2''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                            & [1]\\
                6''-acetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                            & [1]\\
                2'',3''-diacetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                      & [1]\\
                3'',4''-diacetil-apigenina-7-\emph{O}-glucósido                      & [1]\\
                Palmatósido A                                                        & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Triterpeno}\\
                Ácido oleanólico                                                     & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Glicósido fitoesterol}\\
                $\beta$-sitosterol glucósido                                         & [1]\\
                Estigmasterol-3-glucósido                                            & [1]\\  
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Fitoesterol}\\
                $\beta$-sitosterol                                                   & [1]\\
                Estigmasterol                                                        & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Benzofurano}\\
                Matriisobenzofurano                                                  & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Ácido cinámico}\\
                Ácido-(E)-glucometoxicinámico                                        & [1]\\
                Ácido-(Z)-glucometoxicinámico                                        & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Fenólico}\\
                \emph{p}-hidroxiacetofenona                                          & [1]\\
                Ácido 5-cafeoilquínico                                               & [1]\\
                Ácido 3-cafeoilquínico                                               & [1]\\
                Ácido 4-cafeoilquínico                                               & [1]\\
                Ácido 1-\emph{O}-glicósido-ferúlico                                  & [1]\\
                Ácido 7-\emph{O}-glicósido-ferúlico                                  & [1]\\
                Ácido-1,3-dicafeoilquínico                                           & [1]\\
                Cafeato de etilo                                                     & [1]\\
                Ácido neoclorogénico                                                 & [1]\\
                Ácido clorogénico                                                    & [1]\\
                Ácido criptoclorogénico                                              & [1]\\
                Ácido 3,4-dicafeoilquínico                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 3,5-dicafeoilquínico                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido 4,5-dicafeoilquínico                                           & [1]\\
                Ácido isoclorogénico B                                               & [1]\\
                Ácido isoclorogénico C                                               & [1]\\
                Ácido 4-hidroxi-benzoico                                             & [1]\\
                5-pentadecylbenceno-2,3-diol                                         & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Cumarina}\\
                Herniarina                                                           & [1]\\
                Dafnina                                                              & [1]\\
                Dafnetina                                                            & [1]\\
                Esquimina                                                            & [1]\\
                Umbeliferona                                                         & [1]\\
                Esculetina                                                           & [1]\\
                Cumarina                                                             & [1]\\
                Isoescopoletina                                                      & [1]\\
                Escopoletina                                                         & [1]\\
                Fraxidina                                                            & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Esteroide}\\
                7,22-dieno-3,5,6-trihidroxiergosterol                                & [1]\\
                3-$\beta$-hidroxi-5-$\alpha$,8-$\alpha$-epidioxyergosta-6,22-dieno   & [1]\\
                3-$\beta$-hidroxi-(22\emph{E},24\emph{R})-ergosta-5,8,22-trien-7-ona & [1]\\
                6-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmasta-4,22-dien-3-ona                          & [1]\\
                6-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmastero-4-en-3-ona                             & [1]\\
                Estigmast-22-eno-3,6-diona                                           & [1]\\
                5-$\alpha$-estigmasta-3,6-diona                                      & [1]\\
                7-$\alpha$-hidroxiestigmasterol                                      & [1]\\
                7-$\beta$-hidroxiestigmasterol                                       & [1]\\
                7-$\alpha$-hidroxisitosterol                                         & [1]\\
                7-$\beta$-hidroxisitosterol                                          & [1]\\
                $\beta$-sitosterol                                                   & [1]\\
                Fitol                                                                & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Ciclitol}\\
                Ácido quínico                                                        & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Glicósido}\\
                Camolol                                                              & [1]\\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Flavonoide glucurónido}\\
                Bracteósido                                                          & [1]\\
               \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Neolignano }\\
                Coniferil isovalerato dimérico                                       & [1]\\
               \midrule
              \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Monoglicérido}\\
                Glicerol monopalmitato                                               & [1]\\
                \hline
            \end{supertabular}

    \section{Section III}
    \lipsum[1-5]    
    \section{Section IV}
        \lipsum[1-20]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @leandriis, thanks! I really like this new design, it is more elegant, so I will use it in my final document. Thanks again!